# How to calculate the reset time?

Tags: pid-controller, controller

I have a little difficulty on my project. Can I calculate Reset Time (Ti) if I just had the value of P gain, I gain, D gain, Process Variable, and Manipulated Variable? Is there any reference about this task?

Comment: There are loads of PID references on the web.  The reset time is the same as the integral time.  You'll also find the derivative called the rate.

Comment: Reset time is simply the time for the integrator output to change one width of the proportional band.

Answer (score 1):

The best way, if possible, is to tune the parameters rather than 'calculating' them.

The reset time, or integrating time constant, \$T_i\$, is *roughly* the time your controller takes to overcome steady-state errors.

To tune it, you can just start from a high value and slowly reduce it checking out the performance of a step-response (quick change in reference to your controller). As soon as you are satisfied with the promptness of the response and the (eventual) amount of overshoot you introduced, you are finished.

If you really want to 'calculate' the value, you just have to choose one of the hundreds avaliable [PID tuning rules of thumb](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=pid%20tuning%20rule). Note though that not all of them define \$T_i\$ directly just as a function of the other values, but rather define all parameters together.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short this is a function of the dampening period. You have to control it with your properly tuned transfer function. Please take a look at this reference for an in depth explanation.

http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/courses/cds101/fa04/caltech/am04_ch8-3nov04.pdf

To follow up, you want a reset time, which during tuning can be measured as resets per minute. This reset can be seen as whenever your oscillations die down. This oscillation dampening (to whatever dampening percentage you need) can be measured via your transfer function. Solve for dampening time.